# django template add two variables

Tags: django, django-templates

how can I add two or more variables in django template?

here is my template code:

```
{% for cap in capital %}
    {{cap.capital_type}}
    {{cap.capital_amount}}
{% endfor %}

   Total Capital: {{total_capital}}
```

where {{total_capital}} will be sum of cap.capital_amount

Comment: You add two entries in the dictionary you pass as context to the template.

Comment: Plz share your views.py